# Is there a way I can tell what OPTION (FAST 1) does at the end of my query?

Tags: sql-server

I have a number of horribly large queries which work ok on small databases but when the volume of data gets larger then the performance of these queries get slower.  They are badly designed really and we must address that really.  These queries have a very large number of LEFT OUTER JOINS.  I note that when the number of LEFT OUTER JOINS goes past 10 then performance gets logarithmically slower each time a new join is added.  If I put a OPTION (FAST 1) at the end of my query then the results appear nearly immediately.  Of course I do not want to use this as it firstly, it is not going to help all of the time (if it did then every query would have it) and secondly I want to know how to optimise these joins better.  When I run the query without the OPTION set then the execution plan shows a number of nested loops on my LEFT OUTER JOINS are showing a high percentage cost, but with the option off it does not.  How can I find out what it does to speed the query up so I can reflect it in the query ?

I cannot get the query nor the execution plans today as the server I am on does not let me copy data from it.  If they are needed for this I can arrange to get them sent but will take some time, in the morning.

Your comments would be really interesting to know.

Kind regards,

Derek.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does OPTION FAST in SELECT statement do?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135455/what-does-option-fast-in-select-statement-do). I also suggest the documentation: [Hints (Transact-SQL) - Query: Arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query?view=sql-server-2017#arguments)

Comment: Also, I doubt that the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is the problem. I suspect it's more likely to be non-SARGable `WHERE`/`ON` clauses and/or poor and even lack of indexing. Knowing the Query you're running, and the query plan, will be the things that will help us help you the most, if you're looking for advice on how to improve your query.

Comment: Thank you Larnu..  I will get the plan and query asap.  A DBA who works for the client the query is based with mentioned the indexes are ok, we added one yesterday which in test sped it up from minutes to 7 seconds but in a working environment it is so slow..  I think locks are causing the issue but I cannot prove it..  I will be in touch again with more data ..  thanks for your input.  Derek.

Answer (score 0):

You can set column to primary key and column automatically will be Clustered Index.

**Clustered Index->Benefit and Drawback**

Benefit: Performance boost if implemented correctly

Drawback: requires understanding of clustered/non clustered indexes and storage implications

Note: varchar foreign keys can lead to poor performance as well. Change the base table to have an integer primary key instead.

And also

I would suggest to use database paging(f.e. via ROW_NUMBER function) to partition your result set and query only the data you want to show(f.e. 20 rows per page in a GridView).

Comment: Without knowing a lot about the OP's query, and existing definitions, this is a complete stab in the dark. What if the OP is performing a `JOIN` that isn't on a PK/FK relationship? What if they already have a clustered index (it doesn't always go on the Primary Key). Although this response may provide good advice, it's unlikely it's going to provide the answer unless you have far more intimate information about the OP's data that they've shared; and then this question (and answer) becomes somewhat unhelpful to future readers.

Comment: *"Note: varchar foreign keys can lead to poor performance as well. Change the base table to have an integer primary key instead."* Could you explain why? if you have an ascending primary key, there's *unlikely* to be a problem. An `int` could still cause problems as well if you aren't always using an ascending value (for example, people like to reuse "gaps" when they delete rows, which is normally a "bad" idea).

Comment: For More Information You can refer this site,Sir,                                                                                       https://dataedo.com/blog/why-there-are-no-foreign-keys-in-your-database-referential-integrity-checks

Comment: Important information that is relevant to the answer should be in the answer, and then the source cited. Comments can be, and are, missed. That page, however, makes no mentioned of `varchar` and why it's "bad". Could you explain your reasoning please?

Comment: There's only one reason varchar keys are bad. They usually take up more space than a numeric or date/type value. Other than that, the issues presented previously are about index maintenance which would present problems as well.